# How to find all classes on parse core database?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have multiple classes on my app project on parse and I was wondering if there is a way where I can get ALL the class names with a query on objective-c? 
Below is the code I have.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ClassNameID"];
        [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"key" block:^(PFObject *key, NSError *error) {

        //code goes here

        }];
```

`ClassNameID` is the classname on my parse database, but I want the user to select its own database that I have on parse, how do I get all the classnames?

Comment: Use sub classing of parse.
https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-subclasses

Answer (score 0):

You have to use REST Schema API to get all of your Class details in your app instead of a query.

From Parse blog: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/releasing-the-schema-api/

Documentation: https://www.parse.com/docs/rest/guide#schemas